# cannot bind TokenAcquirerFactory to azure app configuration(daemon application calling a custom Web API)

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have been following this tutorial to create daemon application calling a custom Web API with its own identity using a CIAM tenant.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ciam-dotnet-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization/3-call-own-api-dotnet-core-daemon/README.md

everything works fine, the problem I am currently facing.

```
// Get the Token acquirer factory instance. By default it reads an appsettings.json
// file if it exists in the same folder as the app (make sure that the 
// "Copy to Output Directory" property of the appsettings.json file is "Copy if newer").
var tokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance();
```

By default TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance(); reads an appsettings.json, instead I would like to use my own azure app configuration. I was able to change the following

```
tokenAcquirerFactory.Services.AddDownstreamApi(ServiceName,
    tokenAcquirerFactory.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"));
```

to

```
 tokenAcquirerFactory.Services.AddDownstreamApi(ServiceName,
         config.GetSection("DownstreamApi"));  //this now successfuly reads section from azure app config which is  static IConfigurationRoot config
```

I tried the same with the default token factory, but it doesnt work
TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance(config.GetSection("AzureAd"));

I also tried:

```
tokenAcquirerFactory.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityApplicationOptions>(option =>
        {
            config.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(option);
        });
```

and

```
 tokenAcquirerFactory.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
    {
        config.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(option);
    });
```

Is there any way how to overide this functionality, I dont want to store anything in appsettings.json, how to change this default behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work after a small hint from the owner of the github repository.

```
 static IConfigurationRoot config

     builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
     {
         options.Connect(configUrl)
                .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                {
                    kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                })
                .ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
                {
                    refreshOptions.Register("ApiApp:IsRefresh", true);
                    refreshOptions.SetCacheExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                });
     });

     config = builder.Build();

   var tokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance();

   tokenAcquirerFactory.Services.AddDownstreamApi(ServiceName,
        config.GetSection("DownstreamApi"));

   var clientDescription = new List<CredentialDescription>
   {
       new CredentialDescription { ClientSecret =  config["ClientSecretRedemption"], SourceType = CredentialSource.ClientSecret }
   };

   tokenAcquirerFactory.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityApplicationOptions>(options =>
   {
       options.Authority = config["AzureAdAuthority"];//seems like this is useless and needs to be hardcoded in appsettings.json anyway
       { options.ClientId = config["AzureAdClientId"]; }; { options.ClientCredentials = clientDescription; } }) ;
```

and apsettings json needs to stay like this otherwise you get an object reference exception if you remove hardcoded authority and if you remove the whole file TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance() will throw Failed to load configuration from file exception. This is not ideal but still can safely load that from the cloud instead of having the actual values inside the application.

```
{
  "AzureAd": { 
    "Authority": "https://{yourtenanthere}.ciamlogin.com",
    "ClientId": "",
    "ClientCredentials": [
      {
        "SourceType": "",
        "ClientSecret": "" 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```